# JPQL join for eager fetch association

Tags: java, sql, database, jpa, jpql

Say I have entity A that is the parent with `@OneToMany` association to entity B. Also say I set fetch mode to eager. 
So when I use a JPQL to fetch my entities A base on some filter do I need to use join in order to get its children?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use `join` when children are part of the query, for example:

```
select p 
from parent p 
inner join p.children c 
where c ...
```

but you don't have to use `fetch` before join to initialize entities.